# Sitecore 9.3 FXM API 403 error

Tags: sitecore-api, fxm

We are getting a `403 error` when creating an external site in console logs and the following error message in External Site page:

```
Could not validate beacon script - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

[image]

I see the following error in console log:

[image]

When I access the API Url directly I get the following message:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","ExceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}
```

Any help with this will be great.

Comment: Not sure how your external app is configured and built, but can you verify if CORS is enabled in your external application?

Comment: Yes, cors is enabled in external site

Comment: Can you verify if you have enabled the Sitecore.Services.Client.FXM.Enabler.config.disabled config file located at /App_Config/Include/FXM?

Comment: Are you making call from http to https or https to https?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to have enabled the `Sitecore.Services.Client.FXM.Enabler.config.disabled` config file located at `/App_Config/Include/FXM` and that CORS is enabled on the external website.

Regarding the `anti-forgery error`, only the Experience Analytics application should access the API endpoints. You are not supposed to access them directly from the browser—it's not going to work since your request does not include an anti-forgery token. So receiving that error is in fact intended behavior.